# is_unique in codeigniter for edit function

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

i have requirement , where i m able to do validation for unique value in new add function like

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email','required|valid_email||is_unique[users.Email]');
```

its working but in edit function its not working..i have written callback function to check unique email.
this is code i have written in edit function

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email','required|valid_email|callback_check_email');

function check_username($email)
    { 
        $return_value = $this->user_model->check_email($email);
        if ($return_value)
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('email_check', 'Sorry, This username is already used by another user please select another one');
            return FALSE;
        }
        else
        {
        return TRUE;
        }
    }
```

and user_model

```
function check_mail($email)
    { 
        $sql = "SELECT users.Email
                FROM users
                WHERE 
                $email = users.Email
                ";

        $result = $this->db->query($sql)->result_array();
        return $result;

    }
```

i m not able to validate the unique email

Comment: the function name in your user_model is different from the one being called in the controller. if it's not a typo then I think that's the problem. otherwise, I think Arun's answer will work but it's not very clean to have database operation in the controller (IMO)

Comment: use callback function, on update rules

Answer (score 9):

### Try this code in your controller (edit view)

```
    $original_value = $this->db->query("SELECT EMAIL FROM users WHERE id = ".$id)->row()->EMAIL ;
    if($this->input->post('username') != $original_value) {
       $is_unique =  '|is_unique[users.EMAIL]';
    } else {
       $is_unique =  '';
    }
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'User Name', 'required|min_length[3]|max_length[30]|trim|xss_clean'.$is_unique);
```

Comment: try to change  your post values and table fields

Comment: it is a solution but not a good idea if is_unique will be used in many instances

Comment: I have downvoted because the solution only covers the real problem. It means that when editing the field you can use any other existing email as long as when creating you have used a unique one.

Answer (score 5):

**Simple solution**, inspired by is_unique code from CodeIgniter.

**Warning:** Only works if the identifier of the row in the database is the typical "id". Although, this code can be suited easily.

Change is_unique to edit_unique, and concatenate the id of the row that you are editing, like this:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email','required|valid_email|edit_unique[users.Email.'.$id.']');
```

Then go to application/libraries folder and create MY_Form_validation.php with this code:

```
<?php

class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation{

    public function edit_unique($str, $field)
    {
        sscanf($field, '%[^.].%[^.].%[^.]', $table, $field, $id);
        return isset($this->CI->db)
            ? ($this->CI->db->limit(1)->get_where($table, array($field => $str, 'id !=' => $id))->num_rows() === 0)
            : FALSE;
    }

}
```

Then edit this file: application/system/language/english/form_validation_lang.php

And add this code at the end of the file:

```
$lang['form_validation_edit_unique']= 'The {field} field must contain a unique value.';
```

:D

Answer (score 3):

Suppose system provide you to update your username in the application then:-

**File >> config/form_validation.php**

```
$config = array(
    "add_user" => array(
        array('field' => 'name','label' => 'name','rules' =>'required','errors' => array(
            'required' => '%s is required.' 
        )),
        array('field' => 'username','label' => 'username','rules' =>'required|is_unique[tbl_users.username]','errors' => array(
            'required' => '%s is required.',
            'is_unique' => 'Sorry, that %s value is already being used.', 
        )),
        array('field' => 'password','label' => 'password','rules' =>'required','errors' => array(
            'required' => '%s is required.' 
        )),
    ),
    "update_user" => array(
        array('field' => 'name','label' => 'name','rules' =>'required','errors' => array(
            'required' => '%s is required.' 
        )),
        array('field' => 'username','label' => 'username','rules' =>'required|callback_unique_username','errors' => array(
            'required' => '%s is required.' 
            'unique_username' => 'Sorry, that %s value is already being used.' 
        )),
        array('field' => 'password','label' => 'password','rules' =>'required','errors' => array(
            'required' => '%s is required.' 
        )),
    )
)
```

**File >> controller/Users.php**

```
    public function unique_username($username){
        /* 
        * At the time of update you will be needing the user_id 
        * of particular user whose profile you want to update
        * we have placed user_id as hidden field in user update view 
        * form like 
        * <input type="hidden" value="{user_id here}" name="user_id">  
        */ 
        $this->db->where_not_in('user_id',$this->input->post('user_id'));
        $this->db->where('username',$username);
        if($this->db->count_all_results('tbl_users') > 0){
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

To improve on "DrPollit0" solution that only support "id" as column name.
This solution allow you to declear your column name like columnID

Create a custom validation class in application\libraries\MY_Form_validation.php

```
class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation
{
    public function __construct($rules = array())
    {
        $this->CI =& get_instance();
        parent::__construct($rules);
    }

    public function edit_unique($str, $field)
    {
        sscanf($field, '%[^.].%[^.].%[^.].%[^.]', $table, $field, $columnIdName, $id);
        return isset($this->CI->db)
            ? ($this->CI->db->limit(1)->get_where($table, array($field => $str, $columnIdName .'!=' => $id))->num_rows() === 0)
            : FALSE;
    }
}
```

Add this to system\language\english\form_validation_lang.php

```
$lang['form_validation_edit_unique']= 'The supplied value is already taken.';
```

To use in your controller

```
$id = $this->uri->segment(3);
'rules' => 'trim|required|max_length[50]|edit_unique[mytable.mycolumn.columnID.'.$id.']'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

/* Create MY_Form_validation.php  in ci_root/application/libraries */

class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation {

public function is_unique($str, $field) {

    if (substr_count($field, '.') == 3) {
        list($table, $field, $id_field, $id_val) = explode('.', $field);
        $query = $this->CI->db->limit(1)->where($field, $str)->where($id_field . ' != ', $id_val)->get($table);
    } else {
        list($table, $field) = explode('.', $field);
        $query = $this->CI->db->limit(1)->get_where($table, array($field => $str));
    }

    return $query->num_rows() === 0;
}

}
?>



<?php

/* implementation */

function update() {

$user_id = $this->input->post("user_id");
$rules = array(array(
        'field' => 'email',
        'label' => 'Email',
        'rules' => 'required|valid_email|is_unique[users.Email.id.' . $user_id . ']'));

$this->form_validation->set_rules($rules);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $original_value = $this->db->query("select role_name from user_roles where iduser_roles = ".$iduser_roles)->row()->role_name ;
        if($this->input->post('role_name') != $original_value) {
            $is_unique =  '|is_unique[user_roles.role_name]';
        } else {
            $is_unique =  '';
        }

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('role_name', 'Role Name', 'trim|required|xss_clean'.$is_unique);
```

Comment: Good one. But what about the custom messages.

Answer (score 0):

Like that is more flexible:

```
public function edit_unique($str, $field)
    {
        sscanf($field, '%[^.].%[^.].%[^.]', $table, $field, $value);
        return isset($this->CI->db)
            ? ($this->CI->db->limit(1)->get_where($table, array(''.$field.' !=' => $value))->num_rows() === 0)
            : FALSE;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove double **||** and place single **|** just before is_unique and your function name 
**check_username** should be the name you given just after **callback_** means it should be **check_email** in your case.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16261058)

Comment: I am just using basic use of the site like asking questions, answering and it does not require any reputation at all as per [Reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) documentation.